# What is liveness failure?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have seen **liveness failure** mentioned at various places but failed to comprehend it completely or to find some good or any definition on the Internet.

[Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/liveness.html) states that liveness is

> a concurrent application's ability to execute in a timely manner

I expected it to be inability or failure of program/thread to advance/terminate as in cases when it's for example stuck in endless loop or in deadlock. However I am not sure how to interpret 'timely manner'.

Would someone please provide an example of a liveness failure?

Comment: 'Timely manner' means 'having adequate performance.'  When your concurrent application is no faster than a single-threaded one, it is no longer executing in a 'timely manner.'

Comment: I believe you stop performing in a timely manner when you spend more time in context switching (or hard waiting) than you do in computation.

Comment: This is easily answerable via a Google search... Given that SO is not a discussion forum, and its purpose is not to duplicate information easily located elsewhere, this question could be considered off-topic.

Comment: http://java-faqs.com/what-is-thread-liveless/

Comment: @JimGarrison why do you think that's given? It's been discussed in length, and the consensus has been that we *should* duplicate the information that can be googled, and we *should not* request people to google (see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers), for example)

Comment: @JimGarrison We're not concerned with how 'easy' or 'hard' a question is (or "answerable in a google search"), we're concerned with how well written a question is.  

Where this question falls is that the OP has not provided us with any code, or any actual code for us that would demonstrate the issue.  Even a reference to the spec or source for the appropriate library would be helpful.